# Office365 get list of emails to which messages are sent and list of email addressses which received messages

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I'm new to office 365.

How to get list to include the email addresses of anyone who has emailed anyone in the company and anyone who they have emailed-since office365 account is active

With `get-recipients` i can get only current active emails, but no clue how to get sender list ?

Comment: Found answer:http://www.itprotoday.com/office-365/exchange-message-tracing-extended-90-days-office-365-what-about-premises-version